# How to short this view code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have included given code in my view

```
<% if employee.profile.present? %>
   <%= employee.profile.name %>
<% end %>
```

Please guide me how to dry this code

Comment: First of all, fix indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways I would suggest.

1. `<%= employee.profile.try(:name)  %>`
2. `<%= employee.profile.name if employee.profile %>`

Answer (score 2):

An other good solution is to use an helper:

```
<%= has_profile(employee) %>

def has_profile(employee)
  employee.profile.name if employee.profile.present?
end
```